# react access API response

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, redux, fetch-api

Action:

```
export const filesDownload = postData => (dispatch) => {
  console.log(postData);
  fetch(`http://${ip}:8000/api/v1/integrator/email/need_attachment/`, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'content-type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(postData),
  })
    .then(res => console.log(res.json()))
    .then(files =>
      dispatch({
        type: GET_FILES,
        payload: files,
      }));
};
```

Reducer:

```
case GET_FILES : 
  return{
    ...state,
    file: action.payload
  }
```

Component:

```
OnEnableDisplay = (event) => {
  this.props.filesDownload(attachements_call);
};
```

Above is my code I want to access the response from the API which I get in the action in the component and set the state again so that I can show the data I get.

I am new to redux, please spare a little time to help guys.

Comment: Can you provide information regarding the problem/error you are facing? How are you connecting your component to your redux store?

Comment: hi Pierre C.  the thing is i am sending a variable   and in response i get  data i am not able to  figure out how to access the response of the API which is in the actions.js   and  the function is called  at  dummy.js  how do i get the response in the dummy.js

Comment: function is a called in the component and i need to access the response which is in the  action.js

Comment: You need to connect your Component to your Redux store. I think you should look at the Redux documentation step by step [Redux Basic Tutorial](https://redux.js.org/basics/basic-tutorial). You need to understand the concepts to go forward with your question.

Comment: component is already connected to the redux store  it is just how to bind it to the state in the reducer to access it that i where i am stuck

Comment: Edit your question and show us how your component is connected then. It is important to provide all relevant information in your questions.

Comment: Does the data get to your reducer? try console.logging in the reducer to check